# Connecting Automatic Blind Timer

Tags: electrical, wiring, blinds

I currently have a basic GEWISS GW20560 switch connected to my blinds. I'd like to replace it with an automatic timer. My issue is I can't find the electrical diagram for the switch, to work out the mapping of wires.
Currently the wires are:
[image: GEWISS wire connections]

The timer wires are:
[image: Timer wires]

What is the mapping from GEWISS wires to timer wires?

Thanks!

Comment: at first guess terminal 2 is the neutral and 4 5 6 are the lives, you will have to grab a continuity tester to check which ones get connected when pushing the buttons

Comment: It might help if you included the make/model of the new timer. Someone may be able to find the wiring directions and help you interpret them. Even better if _you_ have the instruction sheet and can include a good pic/scan of them.